# STM32 HAL USB CDC Control Data Decoding / Open Port Detection

Tags: usb, stm32, hal

I get lost trying to figure out how to parse control data in `CDC_Control_FS()` function. Can you point me any documentation about that?

Background:
I am using stm32f103, trying to implement USB CDC communication with HAL libraries. I need to detect if usb port is opened by PC, it should handle power on scenario as well as cable reconnetion during runtime. After some research I think that checking DTR signal may be the (most elegant) solution. I know there is `CDC_Control_FS()` function that delivers all line configuration to stm32f103 from PC driver, but unfortunately I don't know data format / how to extract DTR signal, to be able to set some flag for indicating that usb port is currently open or closed.

Comment: Download the zip file from https://www.usb.org/document-library/class-definitions-communication-devices-12. Within the zip file, there is a document called PSTN120.pdf. Go to chapter 6.3.12 SetControlLineState and see table 18.

Comment: I wonder if your approach really works, i.e. if all operating systems keep DTR deasserted as long as no program has opened the serial port and then assert DTR even if the program does not use hardware flow control. Let us know if you are successful.

Comment: @Codo Thak you good man for the help! Now I see that I was wasting my time trying to find this as I made wrong assumption that this is STMicroelectronics driver specific format.. I have no idea if this is a best and portable way to achieve my goal, but firstly - it will be used with windows only and secondly - I have no better idea how to handle this as HAL don't provides API for that. This is my first trial, I'll let you know if I succeed / fail with that.

Comment: After some tests with different programs on Windows I've found the following:
1. Most programs indeed asserts DTR after port opening. The single one that was not asserting DTR was "Terminal by Br@y++", it have DTR button, so operator handles this manually.  2. All programs de-asserts DTR on port closing.